# Convert a string to a datetime

Tags: vb.net, date, asp.net-3.5

I am developing `asp.net` site using `vb` **framework 3.5**.

Im having difficulties converting string data into Date
I tried using cdate function,

I have a variable  sdate which is a string variable and date is stored in it which comes from textbox as dd/mm/yyyy now i want to convert this string into a Date variable as i need to perform the operations as Add a day or Subtract a day.

Please guide me how to go about this. i get the error on 3rd line as,`String was not recognized as a valid DateTime`. I have tried to do as follows but the error comes

```
Dim sdate As String 
Dim expenddt As Date
expenddt = Date.Parse(edate)
expenddt = expenddt.AddDays(-1)
```

But i get the error as

> Conversion from String to type Date is not valid.

How can I get a `Date` from the string?

Comment: Please clarify - are you using VB6 or VB.NET?

Comment: Sorry i have corrected my question

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You should have to use `Date.ParseExact` or `Date.TryParseExact` with correct format string.

```
 Dim edate = "10/12/2009"
 Dim expenddt As Date = Date.ParseExact(edate, "dd/MM/yyyy", 
            System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
```

OR

```
 Dim format() = {"dd/MM/yyyy", "d/M/yyyy", "dd-MM-yyyy"}
 Dim expenddt As Date = Date.ParseExact(edate, format,  
     System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, 
     Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None)
```

OR

```
Dim format() = {"dd/MM/yyyy", "d/M/yyyy", "dd-MM-yyyy"}
Dim expenddt As Date
Date.TryParseExact(edate, format, 
    System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, 
    Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, expenddt)
```

Comment: Thank You.When i debug the expenddt has the vale #12/31/2011# when edate value is 31/12/2011. Why is it so? Why the format gets changed?

Answer (score 7):

Nobody mentioned this, but in some cases the other method fails to recognize the datetime...

You can try this instead, which will convert the specified string representation of a date and time to an equivalent date and time value

```
string iDate = "05/05/2005";
DateTime oDate = Convert.ToDateTime(iDate);
MessageBox.Show(oDate.Day + " " + oDate.Month + "  " + oDate.Year );
```

Answer (score 5):

Try to see if the following code helps you:

```
Dim iDate As String = "05/05/2005"
Dim oDate As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(iDate)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try converting date like this:

```
    Dim expenddt as Date = Date.ParseExact(edate, "dd/mm/yyyy", 
System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think it should be `"dd/MM/yyyy"`. `mm` is for the minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use DateTime.ParseExact method, in which you can specify both of datetime mask and original parsed string.
You can read about it here: [MSDN: DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)

Comment: This is surely VB6 question as I can see OP's code `expenddt = CDate(edate)`

Comment: @Rahul: Using the Visual-Basic Type Conversion Function does not mean that he uses VB6: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy%28v=VS.100%29.aspx