# how to convert string to date in vb.net for compare with current date

Tags: vb.net, date

```
Dim string_date As String 
string_date="31/03/2014"
```

how to convert string_date to date in "dd/MM/yyyy" format to compare with current date

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a string to a date in vb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634568/convert-a-string-to-a-date-in-vb)

Answer (score 1):

Use DateTime.TryParseExact():

```
    Dim string_date As String = "31/03/2014"
    Dim dt As DateTime
    If DateTime.TryParseExact(string_date, "dd/MM/yyyy", Nothing, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, dt) Then
        Debug.Print("dt = " & dt.ToString("D"))
        If dt.Equals(DateTime.Today) Then
            Debug.Print("Equal to Today")
        Else
            Debug.Print("Not Equal to Today")
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: not working properly . everytime control goes out of main if statemnt conversion from string to date is not working

Comment: When your inside the `If` statement, the conversion was successful.  Nothing can be said about the outside of the `If` statement, though, without seeing the entirety of your code.  Did the conversion fail?...or did you just exit the `If` portion?...I don't know.  Show us your code up in the question area by editing it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got my own solution.

```
d1 as date
string_date as string
string_date="31/03/2014"
d1 = Date.ParseExact(string_date, "dd/MM/yyyy", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```