# how to convert string into date? visual basic

Tags: date

I need to convert a date type:

13/09/2014 19:20:32

13: day, 9: month, 2014:year, 19 hours, 20:minutes, 32:second

I used this code:

```
Dim data_convert As Date = Date.ParseExact(data_decripted, "dd/MM/yyyy hh/mm/ss", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
```

but tells me that the string is not recognized as a valid datetime value. How is this possible?

Comment: Try dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a vb.net developer. After searching your requirement I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634568/convert-a-string-to-a-date-in-vb).

You would need to use `Date.ParseExact`.

```
Dim edate = "dd/mm/yyyy" 

Dim expenddt As Date = Date.ParseExact(edate, "dd/MM/yyyy",

    System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
```