# How to convert string to date

Tags: mysql, asp.net, odbc

I have a problem in this line of code:

Dim arrivalDate As Date = Request.Form("startDate")

the error is this: "Conversion from string "" to type 'Date' is not valid."

Comment: Look here for the answer, the issue is not with Mysql: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634568/convert-a-string-to-a-datetime

Comment: thank you for sharing the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use TryParse always to eliminate runtime exception

```
Dim arrivalDate As Date
Date.TryParse(Request.Form("startDate"), arrivalDate)
```

if the value of `Request.Form("startDate")` is not a valid date then arrivalDate will have the value of `Date.MinValue` So have a check before performing further operations

Answer (score 3):

You need to parse the string value to a date.

```
Dim arrivalDate As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(Request.Form("startDate"))
```

See the following [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2h3syy57(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) for more details.

Also if you are unsure of the validity of the `startDate` value (not sure if the string is actually a valid date) you can call TryParse like so:

```
Dim dateValue As Date

If Date.TryParse(Request.Form("startDate"), dateValue) Then
            //Do something
```