# Format Exception when trying to get date in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, date

Can some one guide me on why I am getting this error. I have tried many permutations but I am not able to parse the string and get the date out of it

```
Public Function Starter(starterInput As LoginUserResponse) As List(Of GraphDataObj) Implements iSMS_Rest.Starter
Dim _currentUser = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache(starterInput.tokenProp)
Dim res As Date
Dim provider As Globalization.CultureInfo = Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
Dim dateString As String
dateString = starterInput.dateProp  // VALUE HERE: "2016-08-31T03:59:59.000Z"
res = Date.ParseExact(dateString, "dd/MM/yyyy", provider)
'SOME CODE
End Function
```

Exception I am getting

[image]

I looked into this link for help: [Convert a string to a datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634568/convert-a-string-to-a-datetime)

Comment: The string `"2016-08-31T03:59:59.000Z"` is not of the format `"dd/MM/yyyy"`.  `ParseExact` really means *exact*.

Comment: `ParseExact` means you promise to tell it ***exactly*** what the format looks like. `"dd/MM/yyyy"` is not at all like `2016-08-31T03:59:59.000Z`

Comment: @David: Can you kindly guide me then how can I fetch the date in the dd/MM/yyyy format please.

Comment: @Unbreakable: By inputting a date in that format.  For example, `"15/08/2016"`.  The value is being provided to the method, this code isn't generating the value.  If you want to provide a different value, then provide a different value.

Comment: @David: Thank you for reply. But I could not understand what you mean. In my REST Service I am getting date in `"2016-08-31T03:59:59.000Z"`. Can I some how parse it in "dd/MM/yyyy" format.

Comment: `Dim dt = DateTime.Parse("2016-08-31T03:59:59.000Z")`  its already in a format it can read/parse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you're using is:

```
"2016-08-31T03:59:5‌​9.000Z"
```

Which is *not* the format:

```
"dd/MM/yyyy"
```

It sounds like `ParseExact` isn't what you're looking for.  The input format is a very common date format and will be understood by simply using `Parse`:

```
res = Date.Parse(dateString, provider)
```

(Or, if you don't trust the consistency of the format from the value being provided, you can also [use `Date.TryParse()` instead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx).)

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I trust the consistency because I know how the date is getting passed from from end as I only wrote that code too and I know the input format wil always be like that. Currently from your answer I am getting date as #8/30/2016 11:59:59 PM# . Can I somehow get only in the required format. Do I have any in built methd which can parse it or trim it  only #8/30/2016#.

Comment: @Unbreakable: What do you mean by "getting date as #8/30/2016 11:59:59 PM#"?  The question says the input to this method is "2016-08-31T03:59:5‌​9.000Z".  All this operation results in is a `Date` object.  `Date` objects have no formatting.  You can *output* a `Date` however you like, but in the question you're not outputting anything at all.

Comment: I am sorry for not being clear. I debugged at checked the date that I got after I wrote code as `res = Date.Parse(dateString, provider)`

Comment: I used your suggestion and put that code and then debugged it to see what output its giving.

Comment: @Unbreakable: And what exactly is the problem then?  Are you asking about the difference in the values?  That looks like it's a timezone difference.

Comment: Thank you for being patient with me. Okey here is the thing. I need to pass the date received to another function which accepts date in #8/30/2016# format. So currently I got #8/30/2016 11:59:59 PM#. Since I need to pass only #8/30/2016# format, I need to trim down the  trailing part 11:59:59 PM#. So basically my other function will only work if it gets date as #8/30/2016# WITHOUT any "time" stuff attached to it.

Comment: @Unbreakable: How are you passing this to the other function?  None of that is included in the question.  If you're converting the `Date` to a string then that's where you'd apply your formatting.

Comment: I get what you are saying. Everything is working perfectly fine. I checked the "another function" is accepting  "DATE" as the datatype. So I can always pass  `#8/30/2016 11:59:59 PM#"`. I don't need to trim anything. Thank you so much and sorry for the confusion.