# Converting a string to timestamp format and assign to a Oracle Parameter

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I am trying to assign a string containing the date string to a Oracle Parameter.

```
txtCommence.Text = '31//05/2018' --value is from the textbox

cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter(":pCommencementDate", OracleDbType.TimeStamp)).Value = txtCommence.Text
```

The timestamp in the table is stored as DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM. How to convert the string value in the txtcommence.text to the required format in the table?

Comment: Hopefully the timestamp in database **is not** stored as VARCHAR2 `DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM` - it should be a `TIMESTAMP` or `DATE` value.

Comment: Yes, It is stored as Timestamp(6). That's the datatype of the column i am trying to the insert the value to

Comment: passing a  date value would solve the issue irrespective of the format oracle is using.
try using this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634568/convert-a-string-to-a-datetime to convert string to datetime and pass it to your oracle parameter

Comment: Thanks Ajay, it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If possible you may change your input control from `TextBox` to `DateTimePicker` in order to get a **Date** value directly instead of string.

Anyway, if this is not possible you should change your SQL like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = " ... WHERE COMMENCEMENT_DATE = TO_TIMESTAMP(:pCommencementDate, 'dd//mm/yyyy')"
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter(":pCommencementDate", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = txtCommence.Text
```